# ever with past VS past perfect?

Tags: tense, past-tense

> However, Sol Elman, the father of violinist Mischa Elman, thought differently.  He said, “My dear friends, Kubelik played the Paganini concerto tonight as splendidly as **ever he did.**

Can i change **ever he did** into **he had ever done** or  **he ever did.** without meaning difference?

Comment: Yes. Why might you have doubts about that?

Comment: You mean that he had ever done can be used here without meaning difference,  right?

Comment: I had doubts because there were cases that didnit permit substitutions sometimes:)